# What does Agatha Christie mean with "in a telegraphic style"?

Tags: meaning, agatha-christie

Bold part of this passage from *The Mysterious Affair at Styles*.

> Miss Howard shook hands with a hearty, almost painful, grip. I had an
>   impression of very blue eyes in a sunburnt face. She was a
>   pleasant-looking woman of about forty, with a deep voice, almost manly
>   in its stentorian tones, and had a large sensible square body, with
>   feet to match—these last encased in good thick boots. **Her**
>   **conversation, I soon found, was couched in the telegraphic style.**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When people actually sent telegraphs, they were charged at so much per word. Therefore a prudent correspondent would pare the words down to the minimum necessary to communicate information.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telegram_style#Example

> Telegram style, telegraph style, telegraphic style or telegraphese[1] is a clipped way of writing that attempts to abbreviate words and pack as much information into the smallest possible number of words or characters.

Miss Howard's speech exhibits this characteristic.

> Weeds grow like house afire. Can't keep even with 'em. Shall press
>   you in. Better be careful.

Might otherwise have been expressed as

> The weeds are growing like a house on fire, I can't keep even with
>   them. I shall pressgang you into helping me, so you had better be
>   careful.

Comment: My favourite example of telegraphic conciseness is when novelist Victor Hugo was on holiday at the time his _Les Miserables_ was published: he inquired of his publisher how it was being received by sending the single-character telegram `?` — and received the single-character reply `!`!  There's also the (apocryphal, unfortunately) example of Maj-Gen Charles Napier, commander of the British Indian Army, who had been ordered to subdue rebels in Sindh: after conquering the whole province, he is supposed to have sent the one-word message `peccavi` (which is Latin for ‘I have sinned’).